# Get the first day of week of a year (any programming language)

Tags: dayofweek

How can I get the first day of the week of **any** given year (day being 1 to 7, or weekday name)?

I tried to figure it out in JavaScript, but I accept any other language.

I need to select a year to later build the full calendar (I thought using HTML tables and JavaScript), and for that I need to know at least the first day of the selected year.

I haven't found a solution or a question specifically dealing with finding the first day of **any** given year such that you only need to pass 1995, 2007, 1891. So if it's a repeated question please point the solution.

Do you have at least an online chart or DHTML site where I can see any full calendar for any year visually in that way?

Comment: The first day of any given year is January 1st.

Comment: The first day of any given year is January 1st...in some cultures.

Comment: @asawyer He wants the day of the week, he wrote  `day being 1 to 7, or weekday name`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - get the first day of the week from current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript you can use this:

```
getWeekDay = function (year) {
  var d = new Date(); 
  d.setFullYear(year,0,1);
  return d.getDay()+1;
};

document.write(getWeekDay(2011));
```

Result is 1..7, as requested.

Comment: The result will be 0-6, unless you add 1, as that's what JavaScript returns from `Date.getDay` [MDN Date Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Comment: Just pointing out that it returns 0 to 6. It's just a matter of adding 1 to the result to get 1 to 7.

Comment: In modern JS: `new Date('2023-01-01').toLocaleDateString('en', { weekday: 'long' }); // => Sunday`

Answer (score 2):

With .NET's BCL:

```
return new DateTime(year, 1, 1).DayOfWeek; // DayOfWeek enum value
```

In [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com):

```
return new LocalDate(year, 1, 1).IsoDayOfWeek; // IsoDayOfWeek enum value
```

In Java using the built-in classes:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, 1, 1);
return calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // 1 (Sunday) - 7 (Saturday)
```

In Java using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net):

```
return new LocalDate(year, 1, 1).getDayOfWeek(); // 1 (Monday) - 7 (Sunday)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy with C# and .NET:

```
using System;

public class SomeClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(2000,1,1);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.DayOfWeek);

        dt = new DateTime(2010,1,1);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.DayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Saturday 
Friday
```

---

The Java version:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class test3
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2000,1,1);  
        Date d = c.getTime();
        System.out.println(d.getDay());

        c = new GregorianCalendar(2010,1,1);    
        d = c.getTime();
        System.out.println(d.getDay());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Comment: Date.getDay is deprecated, and I believe the results will depend on your time zone. Not a good idea. `c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

At this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week#An_algorithm_to_calculate_the_day_of_the_week), look for Sakamoto's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This site http://5dspace-time.org/Calendar/Algorithm.html
has a good explanation on how to calculate it even with pencil-and-paper

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week#An_algorithm_to_calculate_the_day_of_the_week) explains it too