# Get date by day of week based from that date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

**Problem**

I'm using AngularJS and in my view I have 7 days in a row like the pic below.  The red, grey, and blue are based on a date (9/1/2013 Sunday).  When I click Friday or Monday I want that date to be returned so I can reload the 0/3 with the stats for that date.

I don't need anything fancy for AngularJS I can't figure out the logic to take a base date and then switch the day out for the day that was clicked.

---

**How do I get this to return a date?**

- Current base date: 9/1/2013 - Sunday
- I click: Thursday
- I receive: 8/29/2013 - Thursday
- I click: Sunday
- I receive: 9/1/2013

---

**What it looks like**

[image]

---

I'm currently trying to convert this function from:

[JavaScript - get the first day of the week from current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date)

```
function getMonday(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  var day = d.getDay(),
      diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
  return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}

getMonday(new Date()); // Mon Nov 08 2010
```

---

## Solved!

I render the dates server side when I render my stats.

Using AngularJS:

- My directives: http://paste.laravel.com/Nz9
- My HTML template: http://paste.laravel.com/Nza
- My PHP: http://paste.laravel.com/Nzc

Comment: I don't know moment.js yet, really, but a quick look at the API and I would guess: `moment([2013, 1, 9]).add('d', clickedDay)`.

Comment: Can you please edit this to ask a question?  I've read it 3 times and I don't see what you are actually asking.

Comment: @MattJohnson I just rewrote my question, sorry I'm having some difficulty wording this is so it's clear and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about what it looks like, let's focus on what data you have.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have an associative array of something like:

```
[{'M',0},{'T',1},{'W',2},{'T',3},{'F',4},{'S',5},{'S',6}]
```

And you also have a base date

```
var base = moment('2013-09-01');
```

And the base is associated with the last value - the 6.

So then what you could do is something like this:

```
var x = 3; // I clicked on Thursday and got a 3
var target = base.subtract('days', 6-x);  // move back 6-x days
```

That would work, but wouldn't it be much easier just to precalculate your associative array in the first place?

```
[{'M','2013-08-26'},
 {'T','2013-08-27'},
 {'W','2013-08-28'},
 {'T','2013-08-29'},
 {'F','2013-08-30'},
 {'S','2013-08-31'},
 {'S','2013-09-01'}]
```

Then you would already know what value to use when it was clicked.

Comment: I went with your advice to just pre render it.  Much simpler and I posted the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with moment's [`day()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) is that Sunday == 0, not Monday, so you have to jump one week back and use the range `1..7` for Monday..Sunday:

```
base = '9/1/2013'
console.log(moment(base).day(-7).day(4))
> Thu Aug 29 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100
console.log(moment(base).day(-7).day(7))
> Sun Sep 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Comment: It seems to be jumping back 7 days when I click the next month. `scope.date = moment(scope.date).day(-7).day(newDay + 1).format("M/D/YYYY");` [Console screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/aiVrkYl.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you post your app on jsfiddle?