# KendoUI scheduler Week view :-how to get date of start of week

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using KendoUI scheduler in my application. is there any way to get the start of week when the selected view is week.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the navigate event to catch current date and get the start of week by manipulating the retrieved date. i.e.

```
navigate: function (e) {
           if (e.view.toLowerCase() === "week") {
                GetStartDateOfWeek(e.date);
             }
  }

function GetStartDateOfWeek(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  var day = d.getDay(),
  diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
  var startOfWeek = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Reference: [JavaScript - get the first day of the week from current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date)