# Javascript : Get the first day of the week passing the current date

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have requirement that we need to pass the current date and get the start date of the week. While doing this the start day is user defined like if the user defines the start day as 0 ,day of the week will be sunday,if 1 then start day will be monday and like wise..
We tried the solution from the link [Start day of the Week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date/4156516#4156516)

But it only handles monday or sunday.

I tried the following code but it will fail select friday or saturday ,it will break

```
var startDate = 5;
if (!d) return;
d = new Date(d);
    var day = d.getDay(),
    diff = d.getDate() - day;
    var sunday = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
    //add days to sunday to adjust sunday,monday,tue,wed...
    return new Date(sunday.getYear(), sunday.getMonth(),sunday.getDate()-(7-startDate));
```

Let me know if any one has idea to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have done so far to get the date or you are referring to the algo in your link?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? What have you tried besides copy/paste from another SO question?

Comment: `But it only handles monday or sunday.` first day of week will always Monday I think ? :p

Comment: @PraveenKumar i have updated the code which i tried ..

Comment: @Jason Cust : I have updated the code which i tried

Comment: Sure... Looks like you are going on with the right way!

Comment: @user3819192 : But in our app,It is user defined..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function getStartOfWeek(index) {
  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDay();
  var diff = index - day;
  if(index > day) {
    diff -= 7; 
  }
  return new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + diff));
}

document.write(getStartOfWeek(0).toLocaleDateString()+"<br/>");
document.write(getStartOfWeek(1).toLocaleDateString()+"<br/>");
document.write(getStartOfWeek(2).toLocaleDateString()+"<br/>");
document.write(getStartOfWeek(3).toLocaleDateString()+"<br/>");
document.write(getStartOfWeek(4).toLocaleDateString()+"<br/>");
document.write(getStartOfWeek(5).toLocaleDateString()+"<br/>");
document.write(getStartOfWeek(6).toLocaleDateString()+"<br/>");
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my "home-made" solution :

```
getWeekStartDate = function(date)
{
    var d = new Date(date);

    // Sunday
    if (date.getDay() === 0) 
        return new Date(d.setDate(date.getDate()-6));

    // Monday
    if (date.getDay() === 1)
        return date;

    return new Date(d.setDate(date.getDate() - (date.getDay() - 1)));
};
```

I work with Date objects but of course you can get the day you were looking for with `date.getDay()`

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I have tried in Jquery and found the solution. Below is the code. It works good.

```
 $first_day_of_the_week = 'Monday';
$start_of_the_week     = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Last $first_day_of_the_week"));
if ( strtolower(date('l')) === strtolower($first_day_of_the_week) )
{
    $start_of_the_week = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('today'));
}
echo $start_of_the_week ;
```