# How do I find startdate and enddate of the week from the specified date

Tags: javascript

I want to find startdate (Monday) of the specified date and lastdate of the specified date in Javascript.
So for example my date is 2015-11-20 , then the startdate should be 2015-11-16 and lastdate should be 2015-11-21

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date

Comment: This works for finding first day but how do I fond the last day?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to do this super easily.

```
var start = moment('2015-11-20').startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Or

```
var end = moment('2015-11-20').endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: But I would have to do it with core js only.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();

$('#start_date').text("Start date: " + subDays(date, day-1));

$('#end_date').text("End date: " + addDays(date, 6-day));


function subDays(date, days){
    return new Date(date.getTime() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString().substr(0,10);
}

function addDays(date, days){
 return new Date(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString().substr(0,10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='start_date'></div>
<br>
<div id='end_date'></div>
```