# How to set datepicker date to first saturday available?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can I set a `datepicker`'s date to the first Saturday available?

Here's my code:

```
jQuery('input#data_da').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' ,
  minDate:  first saturday available
  defaultDate: 0,
  showOn: 'both',
  buttonImage: "/pw/images/sfondo_calendario.png",
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date

Answer (score 1):

You Question bit confusing, what you are asking?

I guess you want to disable all Saturday expect first Saturday of month. if yes. you need to use [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option.

```
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' ,
   defaultDate: 0,
   showOn: 'both',
   buttonText: "Select Date",
   beforeShowDay: function (date) {
     var day = date.getDay();
     var first_week = date.getDate();
     if(first_week <= 7 && day == 6){ // to find first saturday
        return  [true,''];
     }
     if(day == 6){
       return  [false,'']; // disable all saturday
     }
     return  [true,''];
    }
  });
```

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/srsathish/2f0s6hLv/)***

Comment: for example today is 16/09/2016  so i want to show 17/09/2016  in datepiker's label automatically

Comment: so you dont want to hide any dates? you need to show upcoming first saturday date as default in input box right?

Comment: p.s your demo does the opposite that i want to do, also it doesn't show the date in the input label automatically

Answer (score 0):

I found the prefect solution :

```
  jQuery('input#date').datepicker('setDate',  get_first_saturday(new Date));
    function get_first_saturday(d) {
        var day = d.getDay();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6 - day;
                firstsaturday= d.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd  ;
        return new Date(d.setDate(firstsaturday));
    }
```