# HTML5 Date Picker: Week Starting day

Tags: html, input

HTML5 generates a data picker using:

```html
<input type="date">
```

On my browser at least, the week starts on Monday. Is there a way of starting the week on Sunday (or any other particular day)?

Comment: please check once first day of week in your OS date and time settings.

Comment: your check there answer it already available. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date

Comment: @HASEEBALAMRAFIQ No, that question is about using JavaScript to calculate the first day of a given week. This question is about using the browser date picker and setting the first day to Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a lazy solution, I know, but [Jquery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) does the job quite well.

```js
$("document").ready(function () {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({defaultDate: null, firstDay: 1});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

If you want higher security then you can download version 1.13 of jQuery UI on your PC, as 1.12 has some vulnerabities and Google doesn't host the newest version yet.

Comment: Sorry, trying to avoid jQuery, since that’s too much overhead for a simple job. Also all that Google stuff is way too intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant but maybe you can use Javascript for change the First day but i dont know you can try use Javascript but i think you cant change it maybe you can change only on Local maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not something you can do, this feature was not taken into consideration when this element in the markup of HTML was designed.

May be by using a custom date picker library like datepicker.js, you can have more control over the behaviour of the date picker, including setting the starting day of the week.

Hope this helps.